how can allow users to view files on their phone when they are downloaded from my app
async function saveFile(uri: string, filename: string, mimetype: any) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const permissions =
        await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
      if (permissions.granted) {
        const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });

        await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(
          permissions.directoryUri,
          filename,
          mimetype
        )
          .then(async (uri) => {
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log(e));
      } else {
        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: 'Permission Denied',
          text2: 'Please enable storage permission',
        });
      }
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      const documentDirectory = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
      const path = documentDirectory + filename;
      try {
        await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path, uri, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8,
        });

        Toast.show({
          type: 'success',
          text1: 'File saved',
          text2: 'File successfully saved in Documents folder',
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving file:', error);
        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: 'Error saving file',
          text2: 'Please try again later',
        });
      }
    } else {
      Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Unsupported Platform',
        text2: 'File saving not supported on this platform',
      });
    }
  }

In Android its working that users select folder to save their files and then visit that folder to view the files but in ios i am unable to locate where the file has been downloaded please help me out i am using epxo sdk 49 for my app and i want users to view their files that has been downloaded on their phone

Add UIFileSharingEnabled to your info.plist and then save the downloaded files into your app's documents folder - They will be visible in the device "Files" app
